# Stream IPTV through SSL VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, switch, cisco-vpn, igmp

I have a question about streaming IPTV through Cisco ASA5510 ssl vpn.
My current setup at the moment is: 
Public - firewall (asa5510) - L3 switch - L2 switch
But my iptv source feed is coming to L3 switch (not through my fw)

So that setup is working if you want to get the iptv feed in the internal environment.

So my question is: how to make the feed accessible to public through ssl vpn - how should i configure that in my asa5510?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered presenting the stream over a remote desktop session instead,  such as Citrix XenApp/Desktop which might be easier to poke through the SSL VPN..

Comment: Well @TomO'Connor , thank you for replying, the problem here is: im going to run the stream over a various end point devices like using android phone, run over anyconnect and use vlc to get the feed. Thank you.